# SQL views, grouping by most sold items and customers who purchased most

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions, sql-view

This is my table:

[image]

Using this query, I am getting most sold items:

```
SELECT [Purchased Item], SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] )
FROM ReportDraft 
GROUP BY [Purchased Item]
ORDER BY SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] )
```

This returns items and total quantity purchased by customer.

Can I somehow create a table like

```
ItemName | Total quantity purchased | Customer who purchased most | Customer quantity bought

Pie--------|---------11------------|---------------ALEX----------|--------3------------|
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your expected result, why is *Total quantity purchased* 11 and not 6 and how did *Alex*  buy 3?

Comment: yup exactly   ^  this

Comment: I just randomly wrote that result, just to give an idea what I wanted to get

Comment: So you want just a single row returned, the best sold item and the customer who purchsed most? Or one row for each item with it's best customer?

Answer (score 2):

I would use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Purchased Item], sum(total) as total,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Customer END) as customer,
       MAX(Total) as max_quantity
FROM (SELECT [Purchased Item], Customer, SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] ) as total,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY SUM([Overall Quantity purchased]) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ReportDraft 
      GROUP BY [Purchased Item], Customer
     ) rd 
GROUP BY [Purchased Item]
ORDER BY SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] );
```

Comment: couldn't this be simpler written as 2 queries, just sum total quantity purchased as CTE#1, and max quantity bought as CTE#2, then inner join them on itemname?

Comment: Gordon , sorry I am not experienced in sql, I coudnt implement your way

Comment: @Escaper Then probably you should not touch the database, and hire someone who's proficient.  The code is not even complicated.