# SQL views, Groupping + inner join the same table

Tags: sql, database, window-functions

[This is my table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H01Wj.png)

Using this query, I am getting most sold items:

```
SELECT [Purchased Item], SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] )
FROM ReportDraft 
GROUP BY [Purchased Item]
ORDER BY SUM([Overall Quantity purchased] )
```

This returns items and total quantity purchased by customer.

how I can create a table like this

```
ItemName | Total quantity purchased | Customer who purchased most | Customer quantity bought

Pie--------|---------6------------|---------------Tonya----------|--------4------------|
Big Burger-|---------3------------|---------------Tonya----------|--------3------------| and etc
```

Thank you

Comment: you `left join` and `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you post a new question instead of nodifying/extending the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500067/sql-views-grouping-by-most-sold-items-and-customers-who-purchased-most#49500067)?

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT [Purchased Item], 

      -- quantity per item
      SUM(SUM([Overall Quantity purchased]))
      OVER (PARTITION BY [Purchased Item]) AS "Total quantity purchased",

      [Customer name],

      -- quantity per item/customer
      SUM([Overall Quantity purchased]) AS customer_qantity,

      -- rank the customer quantity per item
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY [Purchased Item]
            ORDER BY SUM([Overall Quantity purchased]) DESC) AS rn
   FROM ReportDraft 
   GROUP BY [Purchased Item], [Customer name]
 )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY "Total quantity purchased" DESC
```

Comment: I apologize for it. You code is working great. Can you please recommend some books to read to understand databases more clearly, like what's going behind this lines..

Comment: @Escaper: I read a database beginner's book over 30 years ago, so I can't really recommend one :-)  I usually like the *Head First*  series and I baight *The Manga Guide to Databases*  from my daughter (and she liked it). But as your syntax looks like MS SQL Server it's easy to recommend the books from Itzik Ben-Gan, they cover entry to very advanced level.